# Detecting first and last visible points in an Excel chart wider than Excel window

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have an Excel worksheet that contains a candlestick chart - but for the purpose of this question it might be a regular 2D-line chart, or any chart that has a horizontal axis.

The data source for the chart is not a math function; instead it's arbitrary data representing prices, read from columns of another worksheet.

My chart is many times wider than the worksheet window - and than the Excel window itself. I browse the chart horizontally by simply using the normal horizontal scrollbar of the worksheet, which scrolls the worksheet including the chart in it.

I placed buttons in the same worksheet to manually adjust through VBA code the vertical scale of the chart (Y-axis), because when scrolling horizontally, the new chart values that become visible might require different minimum and maximum Y-axis values to be displayed in an optimal way.

I would like to replace that manual scaling with automatic scaling: after each scroll, I need to know what is the leftmost visible chart point and the rightmost - that is the first and the last visible points. From that I will calculate the best Y-scale and set it into the chart.

So I'm trying to write the VBA code to detect the first and last visible points. The `Chart` object doesn't seem to me to have related methods or properties, and so far I couldn't find ways to do that. So that's my question.

The `Chart.AutoScaling` property won't help as it affects the whole chart, while my goal is to set a vertical scale which is good only for the currently visible portion of the chart. So I need to find the first and last visible  points of the chart.

The users of this chart might have an Excel version as old as Excel 2007, so a solution that works with versions that old would be optimal, but solutions that require newer Excel versions would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rarely post another answer, so this has taken some thinking.

Consider a dynamic chart that shows only a select part of the data, instead of a static chart that shows all data. Consider that instead of building a chart that stretches across multiple screen widths, you could have a single chart that fits the screen perfectly, but the user could determine what they want to see in that chart.

Then give the user a few control cells where they can enter the starting point of the chart data and another control where they can determine how many candles/bars/points they want to see in the chart.

With that information provided by the user, you can apply established dynamic charting techniques like named formulas for chart ranges. Then sprinkle a little VBA on top to determine the min and max of the selected charting range.

Let me know if you want to see a sample of that technique and I'll add a link. It's really not all that hard to do and a much better user experience than scrolling across a chart that disappears off the left and right of the window.

**Edit**: I created a sample file that you can download with this [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jiy1q49202bhhrq/SO44019659.xlsm?dl=0)

You need to enable macros for this file.

The top chart shows all data.

The chart in row 26 uses dynamic ranges. The user can manipulate F17 and F18 to select a starting point and the number of rows to plot. The chart in row 26 then uses the Excel defaults to appropriate the value axis with some padding, as Excel does.

The chart in row 42 (love that number) overrides the Exel defaults and uses the values in F23 and F24 for minimum and maximum values respectively. This is done with a Worksheet Change event macro that runs whenever any cell in the sheet is changed.

There's gazillion ways to fine-tune and improve this approach, like, only fire the macro when the chart parameters in F23 or F24 change, but that's not the point.

The point is that you can use a dynamic range name to show a selection of your data in a chart. Without any code, but letting Excel decide what the Y axis min and max should be. Like the chart in D26.

If you want more control over the min and max of the Y axis, use the code version and the chart in D42.

Happy to take questions.

Comment: This is probably a nicer UI solution, as you say, think my head jumped straight to the interesting problem of detecting the visible chart area! I'm curious what you mean by *"established dynamic charting techniques"*? You could easily do what you're saying without named formulas?

Comment: Great thinking. If you rarely post another answer I'm glad you did so this time. This answer steps back from the original question, captures its context and removes the need for the question itself by suggesting an alternative approach which is probably just The Right Way for this case. I implemented this with the whole data series set into the chart and my brain stuck to that although that wasn't a requirement at all. I'll try to find out if it's proper to mark this as the accepted answer for my question about detecting the visible area, but this solution is the way I'm going to go.

Comment: From the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): *"you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem."* If you're ever unsure, you can ask on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I added a sample file and some explanation of a dynamic chart with dynamic range names that can be used with or without code. Open buffet. Eat what you want.

Comment: Just wow. Most effective help I ever got. Thanks also for pointing out that you would welcome questions. I will start reimplementing the whole charting thing soon along your lines and given the clarity and the examples I probably won't have further questions, but if I will I will ask here. Cheers.

Comment: @Wolfie I went with your suggestion and [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349312/2814308) on meta.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not versed enough in VBA to provide the exact code for this, but conceptually, if you scroll the sheet horizontally, there should be a way to determine the address of the top left cell in the visible window, for example with `ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Cells(1,1)` and along the same lines of logic,  you can determine the last cell of the visible window if you know the column width and the zoom factor.

You can then connect these visible cells and their respective addresses with a related range in the chart data source. For example, if the visible range is columns A to M, then the data range in the chart must be row 1 to 55, if the visible range is columns M to Z then the data range in the chart must be row 55 to 100.  You may need to work out a conversion formula for that relationship.

Then you can grab the pertinent values in the source data that will be plotted in the chart and process the min and max of the value axis.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach, more indirect than what I was hoping for but absolutely worth looking into. Determining the visible columns is certainly possible and probably easy, and coming up with a conversion formula to determine the points range corresponding to a columns range is certainly workable, although complicated by the fact that when I scroll by one column the amount of chart points that "exit" the visible window on the left side (hopefully equal to the amount of points that "enter" the window from the right side) is also to be determined. It's certainly a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to scale your axes according to the visible x values.

I've tried to comment it well, but the logic is as follows:

- Get the visible range using the `.VisibleRange` property
- Get the left and right points of the visible range and the plot area
- Calculate the leftmost and rightmost *visible* x values, then find the closest *actual* data point to each. This avoids having to assume equidistant x data
- Get the indices of those extreme values within the data, so that you can get the corresponding y values.
- Scale the axes to those y values

**Note:** This currently relies on the `ActiveChart` object, it would be *much* more robust to use a defined chart object with a given name. That's up to your specific usage.

Code:

```
Sub scaley()
    ' Get visible range
    Dim visrange As Range
    Set visrange = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
    ' Get left and right in points
    Dim L As Double, R As Double
    L = visrange.Left
    R = visrange.Cells(visrange.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1).Left
    ' Get left and right of chart, relies on chart being active
    ' could easily replace with calling your chart by name
    Dim chtL As Double, chtR As Double
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveChart
    chtL = cht.Parent.Left + cht.PlotArea.Left
    chtR = chtL + cht.PlotArea.Width
    ' Get visible region by percentage
    Dim pL As Double, pR As Double
    pL = WorksheetFunction.Max((L - chtL) / (chtR - chtL), 0)
    pR = WorksheetFunction.Min((R - chtL) / (chtR - chtL), 1)
    ' Get x axis values, and the visible x axis range
    Dim xval() As Variant
    xval = cht.SeriesCollection(1).XValues
    Dim xmin As Double, xmax As Double, xrange As Double
    xmin = WorksheetFunction.Min(xval)
    xrange = WorksheetFunction.Max(xval) - xmin
    xmax = xmin + pR * xrange
    xmin = xmin + pL * xrange
    ' Get actual corresponding x values
    Dim imin As Long, imax As Long
    For imin = LBound(xval) To UBound(xval)
        If xval(imin) >= xmin Then Exit For
    Next imin
    For imax = UBound(xval) To LBound(xval) Step -1
        If xval(imax) <= xmax Then Exit For
    Next imax
    ' Get y values in the visible range
    Dim allyval() As Variant, yval() As Variant
    allyval = cht.SeriesCollection(1).Values
    ReDim yval(0 To imax - imin)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = imin To imax
        yval(i - imin) = allyval(i)
    Next i
    ' scale axes, including buffer so max/min values dont sit right on edge
    Dim buffer As Double
    buffer = 0.1
    cht.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(yval) + buffer
    cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.Min(yval) - buffer
End Sub
```

Here are some example outputs. I used the **arbitrary data** `x = -10, -9, ..., 10` and `y = 100, 81, 64, 49, ..., 81, 100` (which is `x^2`) to create the scatter plot, then ran the sub in different window positions.

The chart size doesn't change, I simply change my window size / scroll, make sure the chart is selected (see "note" above) and run the sub:

[image: zoom 1]

[image: zoom 2]

---

If you actually need to trigger this sub on a scroll event then you might want to look here: [cpearson - DetectScroll](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm). This is not a simple thing to do though! An easier option would be to have a really wide button across the top (or something similar) which could call the above `scaley` sub.

Comment: Thanks, it looks awesome; I'm just trying to figure out from your code if this solution is dependent on the charted values being the result of a function (ex. `y=x^2`), because in my case they are not (I just added this info to the question); but even so I can always get the `y` of a certain `x`. Thanks also for the info and button idea about detecting a scroll; I totally had the feeling that was much easier said than done. Your suggestion prompted me to think that I could add a scroll-left and scroll-right buttons to do the scrolling, and maybe scroll by an amount specified in a certain cell.

Comment: I just used `y=x^2` as an example, this solution is entirely dependant on *whatever data is on your chart*, about half way through I retrieve the chart's `XValues`, and near the end I retrieve the chart's y-values (`Values`), they could have been anything! Adding scroll buttons would be okay, but you may have issues when someone manually scrolls.